# disable fields when selecting a item from dropdown in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do a form and so far i have done everything needed. But the thing is i want to disable several fields when selecting a item from a select dropdown.

For example if i select "within company" option from my transaction type,all the other fields below that should be disable (should not be able to enter data). how can i achieve this?

here i'll post my code

```
<ion-content  class="has-header" scroll="true" padding="true">
<form id="myForm">
   <label><h4><b>Source Account Number</b></h4></label>
   <select id="originAcc"   style="margin: auto; width:100%; " ng-model="data.origin" ng-options="account.account for account in accountsArr">
       <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Account--</option>
   </select><br><br>

<label><h4><b>Transfer Amount</b></h4></label>
<input type="number"  id="amount" name="amount" ng-model="data.amount" class="item-input-wrapper" decimal-places onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode == 46'>
<br>  

<label><h4><b>Beneficiary Account Number</b></h4></label>
<input type="text"  id="beneAcc" name="beneAcc" ng-model="data.beneAcc"  class="item-input-wrapper" >
<br>

<label><h4><b>Beneficiary Name</b></h4></label>
<input type="text" id="beneName" name="beneName" ng-model="data.beneName"  class="item-input-wrapper" >
<br>
<label><h4><b>Transaction Type</b></h4></label>
<select id="transtype"   style="margin: auto; width:100%; " ng-model="transtype" ng-options="type.type for type in types">
   <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Transaction Type--</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<label><h4><b>Select Bank</b></h4></label>
<select id="beneBank"   style="margin: auto; width:100%; " ng-model="data.beneBank" ng-options="bank.bank for bank in banks">
  <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Bank--</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<label><h4><b>Branch Name</b></h4></label>
<select id="beneBank" style="margin:auto; width:100%;" ng-model="data.beneBank" ng-options="bname.bname for bname in bname">
     <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Branch Name--</option>
 </select>
 <br><br>   

<label><h4><b>Fund Transfer Remarks</b></h4></label>
<input type="text"  id="narration" name="narration" ng-model="data.narration" class="item-input-wrapper">

<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="beneficiary"> Save as beneficiary<br><br>

<div class="col" style="text-align: center">
                    <button align="left" class="button button-block button-reset" style="display: inline-block;width:100px;text-align:center " ng-click="reset()" padding-top="true">Reset</button>

                    <button class="button button-block button-positive"  style="display: inline-block;width:100px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; " ng-click="thirdPartySubmit(data)" padding-top="true" >Transfer</button>
                    </div>

        </form>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Listen to `change` event of `<select>` and disable or enable whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-disabled
//////

```
<select id="transtype"   style="margin: auto; width:100%; " ng-model="transtype" ng-options="type.type for type in types" data-ng-change="hideFields()">
                <option value="" selected="selected">--Select Transaction Type--</option>
```

In controller

```
$scope.hideFields = function() {
    if($scope.transtype == "within company") {
         $scope.disableFileds = true;
    }
}
```

In view

```
<input type="text"  id="beneAcc" name="beneAcc" ng-model="data.beneAcc"  class="item-input-wrapper" ng-disabled="disableFileds">
```

// do like this to disable fields

/////////
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: did not work.it did not get disabled when i chose 'Within company'

Comment: `if($scope.transtype == "within company") {` did u replace `"within company"` with the value ?

Comment: i did exactly as u said. i did not replace any value with anything

Comment: you have to replace the `== "within company") {` `within company` with its value

Comment: i have not given any value . this is how i have given my options in the controller.

 $scope.types = [
        { type: 'Within Company' },
        { type: 'SLIPS Transction'  },
        { type: 'CEFT Transction'  },
                                                 
        ];